# how to launch javafx application from another class with default constructor?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, java-threads

I have a main class

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gui gui = new Gui();
    }
}
```

Then i have another class Gui

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Gui extends Application{
    public Gui() {
        Application.launch();
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("");
        FlowPane flowLayout= new FlowPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(flowLayout,200,200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I want to launch Javafx Application from Main class by creating a Gui instance and with default constructor too .
How i can do that ?

Comment: Your Application class is your FX Main Class, I'm not sure why you are trying to call it from another class?  Are you trying to handle non-gui logic and trying to separate that?  IF so then you will call that from your FX Main Class.

Comment: Putting that call in the constructor is a very bad idea: constructor call -> `launch()` call -> creation of instance of Application class (= constructor call). I'm not sure whether this fails with a stackoverflow or complains about calling launch more than once, but it'll fail anyways...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't put the `launch` method call in the constructor; It is a blocking method call and will not return until the application exits.

The GUI default constructor will be called by the `Application.launch` method and you do not need to (and cannot) pass your instance to application launcher. If you really want to call from the `main` method in another class, you may use `Application.launch(Gui.class, args)` directly.

Answer (score -2):

Like this:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gui gui = new Gui();
        gui.main(args);
    }
}
```